# Calculating Percentage of Various Categories that Meet Conditions with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have a table with information about flights between cities that looks like this:

```
    origin_city dest_city   time    
    Dothan AL   Atlanta GA    171    
    Dothan AL   Atlanta GA    171    
    Dothan AL   Elsewhere AL    2    
    Dothan AL   Elsewhere AL    2    
    Dothan AL   Elsewhere AL    2    
    Boston MA   New York NY     5    
    Boston MA   City MA         1    
    New York NY Boston MA       5    
    New York NY Boston MA       5    
    New York NY Boston MA       5    
    New York NY Poughkipsie NY  2
```

I want to find, for each origin city, the percentage of flights that are less than 3 hours long. So the results would be like this:

```
    Dothan AL    60
    Boston MA    50
    New York NY  25
```

The code I thought would work looks like this:

```
     SELECT F.origin_city as origin_city,    
       ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Flights as F2
       WHERE F2.actual_time < 3) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Flights as  F3)) * 100
     AS percentage
     FROM Flights as F
     GROUP BY F.origin_city
     ORDER BY percentage;
     GO
```

When I run it, I get a list of origin cities and a column for percentage, as expected, but the percentage is always 0. I'm still pretty confused about subqueries (as you can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using `AVG()` as a window function:

```
SELECT F.origin_city as origin_city, 
       AVG( CASE WHEN F2.actual_time < 3 THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) as percentage
FROM Flights F
GROUP BY F.origin_city
ORDER BY percentage;
```

This assumes that the time is measured in hours.  According to Google Maps, you can walk from Dothan to Atlanta in 68 hours, so the 171 is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Your percentage is over the whole table rather than the group by origin city. Try something like this:

```
 SELECT F.origin_city as origin_city,    
   (SUM(CASE WHEN F.actual_time < 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) )  * 100 AS percentage
 FROM Flights as F
 GROUP BY F.origin_city
 ORDER BY percentage;
 GO
```

FWIW the issue with your current sub query is that you have no join between your current row and the data in the sub query. You could probably rewrite it as something like:

```
 SELECT F.origin_city as origin_city,    
 ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Flights as F2
 WHERE F2.origin_city = F.origin_city and F2.actual_time < 3) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Flights as  F3 where F3.origin_city = F.origin_city)) * 100
 AS percentage
 FROM Flights as F
 GROUP BY F.origin_city
 ORDER BY percentage;
 GO
```

But it's kind of unnecessary to re-query the table for every row when you already have enough data to do your calculation as shown above.